# 'System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.DbUpdateException' I dont know why my program is throwing me this error

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I am an amateur to web programming. 
Currently working with c#, MVC, js/ts, and jquery.

When I try and SaveChanges to my database I get this error:

> " 'System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.DbUpdateException' occurred in
>   EntityFramework.dll. Additional information: An error occurred while
>   updating the entries. See the inner exception for details. "

There are no inner details. This is what I am trying to do.

```
        Order order = new Order();
        TryUpdateModel(order);

        try
        {
            if (string.Equals(values["PromoCode"], PromoCode,
                StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase) == false)
            {
                return View(order);
            }
            else
            {
                order.Username = User.Identity.Name;
                order.OrderDate = DateTime.Now;

                //Save Order
                storeDB.Orders.Add(order);
                storeDB.SaveChanges();
                //Process the order
                var cart = ShoppingCart.GetCart(this.HttpContext);
                 cart.CreateOrder(order);

                return RedirectToAction("Complete",
                    new { id = order.OrderId });
            }
        }
        catch (System.Data.Entity.Core.UpdateException e)
        {
            return View(order);
        }

        catch (System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.DbUpdateException ex) //DbContext
        {
            Console.WriteLine(ex.InnerException);
            return View(order);
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(ex.InnerException);
            //Invalid - redisplay with errors
            return View(order);
        }
```

it fails at `cart.CreateOrder(order);`

this is what CreateOrder(order) does

```
        decimal orderTotal = 0;

        var cartItems = GetCartItems();
        // Iterate over the items in the cart, 
        // adding the order details for each
        foreach (var item in cartItems)
        {
            var orderDetail = new OrderDetail
            {
                GameId = item.GameId,
                OrderId = order.OrderId,
                UnitPrice = item.Game.Price,
                Quantity = item.Count
            };
            // Set the order total of the shopping cart
            orderTotal += (item.Count * item.Game.Price);

            storeDB.OrderDetails.Add(orderDetail);

        }
        // Set the order's total to the orderTotal count
        order.Total = orderTotal;

        // Save the order
        storeDB.SaveChanges();
        // Empty the shopping cart
        EmptyCart();
        // Return the OrderId as the confirmation number
        return order.OrderId;
```

it gives me the error message at storeDB.SaveChanges();
everything is spelt the way it is suppose to.

Anything you guys think I am missing?

Comment: Can you please check the `OrderId` getting populated in `order` object after you save the `order` for the first time before making the call to `storeDB.SaveChanges();`? Does it have some valid value which is reflecting in your database as well?

Comment: @RBT Yes it has a valid value in my database. Also I think you understood when I said the problem is here  `order.Total = orderTotal // Save the order
        storeDB.SaveChanges();`(with saveChanges)  not here->`storeDB.Orders.Add(order);
                storeDB.SaveChanges();`

Comment: @RBT everything with order is fine, its orderDetails that is having the problem

Comment: Can you please add DDL scripts of both the tables namely `Order` and `OrderDetail` in to your post? Also post the class definitions in your C# code. That is the only way I can reproduce it on my machine. With current code in your post, things look good to me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We figured it out. When saving our changes to the database we forgot to fill in a column for that entry. Very stupid =P. I was working with a partner and thought they took care of all that stuff.

Thanks guys

Answer (score 0):

The DbUpdateException is caused by mostly database constraint violations. You should be showing the additional code to deal with the DbUpdateException:

```
try 
{
    ....
}
catch (DbUpdateException ex) 
{
    UpdateException updateException = (UpdateException)ex.InnerException;
    SqlException sqlException = (SqlException)updateException.InnerException;

    foreach (SqlError error in sqlException.Errors)
    {
        // TODO: Do something with your errors
    }
}
```